# C++ accesing method of an instance stored in a std::vector containing template class of multiple types

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I wish to access to the method **setProperty** of the class GraphProperties stored in a vector. Since my class GraphProperties is a template I have to define the vector the parent class of GraphProperties. However, defining virtual method template in **GraphPropertiesAnyType** is not allowed. Is there any solution to get access to the method **setProperty** from the element stored in my vector.

```
class GraphPropertiesAnyType {
public:
    GraphPropertiesAnyType() = default ;

    template<typename P>
    virtual void setProperty(int v, P property) = 0; // not allowed 
};

template <typename P>
class GraphProperties : public GraphPropertiesAnyType
{
public:

    GraphProperties() = default ;

    GraphProperties(std::string name): name(name) {};

    void setProperty(int v, P property)
    {
        auto p = std::make_pair(v.first, property);
        this->property.insert(p);
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    std::map <int, P> property;
};
```

## Main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GraphPropertiesAnyType> > v ;
      std::unique_ptr<GraphProperties<int, int, int> > elem;
      v.push_back(elem); // work fine
      v[0].setProperty(5, 10); // my issue is there
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.   What is your "issue"?   By that I mean you need to describe the compiler error (or whatever) rather than assuming people will know what you call an "issue".

Comment: `template<typename V, typename P> virtual void setProperty(V v, P property) = 0;` is illegal.  You cannot have a virtual function template.

Comment: No, you cannot have a `setProperty` function without knowing what property to set.

Comment: So I have no choice other than defining a virtual method of all the type I want to use, right ?

Comment: You might look into 'type erasure'. Haven't tried it myself, but the name sounds like it might be helpful.

Comment: Is it feasible to map the properties to a name (string), rather than a typename?